# AngularJS load data in app startup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that must be loaded within (or before) AngularJS's start up (it is a user's profile of permissions that hides/shows parts of the user interface, checking is also done server side).

My first idea was to use:

```
module.run(function() {... })
```

but the nature of async and promises means the profile could be loaded after everything else.

My next idea was to inline the profile as a script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/api/user-profile"></script>
```

Where it returns a JSON global variable like:

```
var userProfile = { ... };
```

and then put the user profile into the root scope during module.run().

This works well but seems dirty.

Basically, I want to load data before or during Angular's startup, like you would with resolve in routes, in that it waits before continuing.

Is there a cleaner approach? Perhaps some kind of Angular service?

Comment: I use a resource or service for my current users data. 
The fact that it may not be loaded until point x doesn't bother me as everything is hidden by default and displayed once it can be confirmed that the user has 'permission' to see.

Comment: @DrewR interesting, perhaps I could move the loading of the user profile into a service that is injected into the base controller, then the base controller handles putting it into scope and the default is to hide stuff till it is loaded...

Comment: Yup. When I say everything is hidden though I don't have ng-hides everywhere - I have generic functionality to determine whether nav items, page features etc should be displayed. And if you use routes or states (angular-ui) you can intercept transitions and prevent them completing if your user doesn't have permission (or indeed delay the state transition until user profile has loaded).

Comment: @DrewR I have a BaseCtrl that everything goes inside so just put 1 ng-show and it works. It hides the page and shows the loading dialog till it is loaded (better than an content flash). Shame you can't accept a comment as the answer!

Comment: Updating an old but popular question. I now use Angular UI Router and nested abstract routes to resolve the data before it's required.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually start Angular.js with `angular.bootstrap`. So that you can load your data first, then when you feel ready. Call `angular.bootstrap()` to start angular module.

What you have to prepare:

1. Remove `ng-app="XXX"` from your document.
2. Call `angular.bootstrap()` after everything is ready.

*[Doc for angular.bootstrap()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap)*