# Bootstrap AngularJS app with data from the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app and I'd like to pre load the $scope or $rootScope with application specific data before any of the controller code is executed. This would include stuff like roles, permissions, localizations, etc.

The only viable option I've found is to add the resolve object to EVERY one of my routes/controllers, I consider this to be a maintenance nightmare.

I also read about application.run(), however there is no way to get the dependencies from the service to resolve. Meaning you may call a service to your server in run, but it will not wait for the promise to finish before continuing on.

I feel like this is a pretty glaring problem with AngularJS.

Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious from the API.

Here is a very similar question, posted over the summer, no real solution was posted though.
[AngularJS load data in app startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352633/angularjs-load-data-in-app-startup?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Normally `resolve` is a good way to do if you want to do something with Angular first, then pause, then do other things with Angular.

But if you want to do something without Angular first, then start Angular, you could manually start Angular.js with `angular.bootstrap`. So that you can load your data first, then when you feel ready. Call `angular.bootstrap()` to start angular module.

What you have to prepare:

1. Remove `ng-app="XXX"` from your document.
2. Call `angular.bootstrap()` after everything is ready.

*[Doc for angular.bootstrap()](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)*

Answer (score -1):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MYContoller', function ($scope)
 {
    $scope.init = function()
    {
       ...
    };
    $scope.init();

  }
```

This should work, you can also use ng-init, bit think that the docs state that you shouldn't